# Why is iOS not overriding background color if I use a custom color from xib?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a xib. I have a view controller that loads the xib and adds it to its subview. The xib has the background color set from the xib file (from interface) to a **CUSTOM COLOR SET** from assets (created by me).
Everything works fine.

Now, inside my view controller, in viewDidLoad I want to override that background color with something else. The problem I found and it replicates 100% is that overriding doesn't do anything, unless I do it in viewDidAppear.

So to sum up...

- **custom color** background set from xib... overriding in viewDidLoad **not working**, overriding in viewDidAppear working
- Xcode **default color** background set from xib (any other color except from assets custom colors)... overriding in viewDidLoad **WORKS**...

Why in the first case I cannot override the color and in the second I can?

Is there a hidden feature that I'm missing here? You simply cannot override a view background color in viewDidLoad if the color set from xib is custom color, but if it's any other color... like white, red, black or w/e Xcode already has everything works as expected.

If it has any impact... this view controller I'm talking about gets pushed on the navigation stack. But I don't see how this can have any impact.

---

#### Reproduction Steps:

To replicate this... create a new sample project... that only has one view controller in it. Next add a custom color via assets -> new color set. Set the view controllers view background color from storyboard to the newly added color set. Then inside viewDidLoad change the background color of the view to something else... you will notice if you run the app it WON'T CHANGE if in storyboard there is a custom color set as background.

Somehow the background custom color set from storyboard overrides happen behind the scenes after viewDidLoad and before viewDidAppear.

Comment: are you overriding after the `super.viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: yes, after super.viewDidLoad...

Comment: it works fine, if the color set from xib is not custom color set... mind blowing. If it's custom color, it only works if I do it in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Where are you adding xib as a subview in viewController?

Comment: what code you have tried?

Comment: there is no code... you just do view.backgroundColor = w/e inside viewDidLoad and it won't work

Comment: @AlinLipan generally this works. background color is just a property. So if you post the code of how you are retrieving your xib, adding it to the view, etc.. maybe someone can give you an answer.

Comment: You don't understand, everything works perfectly except for that line of code in which I change the background color of the view loaded from xib... there are no errors... that line just doesn't do anything if I set custom color from xib... there surely must be something apple did regarding custom colors. I will create a sample project when I have some spare time to show this... but it's really just the basics of loading a view form a xib and adding it as a subview... there is nothing fancy.

Comment: I will edit my post shortly... I have found the basic case... no views needed to be added.

Comment: @AlanS apparently this doesn't generally work even if it's just a property.

Comment: @AlinLipan yes i was able to replicate the scenario you're having and the issue does exist. It's a bug with iOS i guess, i'm not too sure and not sure how others will confirm this. 

I noticed that the new color (set by code in viewDidLoad) does get set until you pass viewWillLayoutSubviews, then it is reset to the color you made from the Color Set. But even though this is a bug, I mean it is quite avoidable. if you use a color not from a color set then it operates normally.

Comment: Ye I know the workaround... I was just trying to make my user interface from xib look like the real app colors... that's the only reason... but in the end I used a default xcode color that's closer and that's that... but it's still mindblowing why this happens :D

Answer (score 8):

I come late but have more info for future readers. 
I just met this bug in my App for iOS 11 and iOS 12. The bug is solved by Apple since iOS 13.0. 
So if you support previous version, you still need to apply the workaround from @AlanS, or not use custom colors in storyboard and xib :

```
func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        // Fix iOS 12 storyboard color bug.
    } else {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this is pretty ugly, so much useless code to write in every view controller. I guess the only way is not using custom colors in storyboards/xibs.

Comment: @AlinLipan, it maybe annoying to do it every time you need to override background color in code. But Asset Colors are very useful for Dark Mode since iOS 13. Most of the time, you should not need to override this property. If it's the case, you can still apply the asset color in code.

Comment: Yeah, I just had the case where I wanted to use a specific custom color in storyboards/xibs to hint that the color will be overwritten at runtime (dynamic color). This is my only inconvenient... but I just used black / light gray instead of custom color to achieve this and that's that.

Comment: wow, thank you! i've been trying to debug this for ages!  of course, i had a solution - but this is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with this issue recently

I had xib file for table cell and custom colors in xcasset.
Colors are single appearance (dark mode not supported).
In cell swift class I have bool variable with didSet, where few outlets are modified: view.backgroundColor and label.textColor. Their values are based on variable value. There are ternar conditions so I was sure that color will be selected correctly.

On devices with iOS 12 (checked on 12.1 and 12.4 real and simulators) color didn't change at start but only after cell reuse.

After finding this question and few experiments, I have found that:
Setting custom color in xib file (no matter, if they have dark version or not) was performed after my didSet block and overrides my conditions results. And since I have set one of possible color in xib, I though that problem in data.

So I have reset outlets colors to default in xib and now it works
In case if you have to display some default color before some conditions, I guess putting it in init methods (awakeFromNib, viewDidLoad etc) should work

This bug was fixed in 13.0+

Duplicating answer from https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649009

Answer (score 0):

One more strange workaround that helped me is to perform color updating code on the main thread.

It worked both in **viewDidLoad** and **awakeFromNib**.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.setupColors()
}

func setupColors() {
    //your colors updating logic//
}
```